# built module is missing 64-bit support titanium

Tags: titanium-mobile

I am building module to run iOS 64bits.

I got this error, please help me to fix this.

Appcelerator: 4.1
TitaniumSDK: 4.1.0.G

```
Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphoneos8.4

=== BUILD TARGET demomodule OF PROJECT demomodule WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator8.4

=== BUILD TARGET demomodule OF PROJECT demomodule WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===

Check dependencies

** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Check build architectures

[WARN] built module is missing 64-bit support.
[WARN] architectures in manifest: x86_64, i386, arm64, armv7
[WARN] compiled binary architectures: i386, armv7

MODULE BUILD FAILED
[ERROR] there is discrepancy between the architectures specified in module manifest and compiled binary.
[ERROR] Please update manifest to match module binary architectures.
```

Comment: Did you follow http://www.tidev.io/2015/01/09/how-to-update-your-app-and-modules-for-64-bit-support/ ? It looks like you have not correctly updated your module's Xcode project.

Comment: First, I tried with your link to extends its compatibility with 64bits, but it is not working. it says "project not found". I am on the root directory of the project and version of ti-64: 2.1.3.

Then I create new module with Appcelerator by copy and paste code. then I build i get above error.

Comment: You should be able to open your original module project and follow http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/release-notes/?version=3.5.0.GA#modules to enable it for 64-bit and then finally update the manifest.

Comment: Yes,  I can open original module. but after I modified the manifest file. then what should I do to build module? I tried to click build from xcode but I dont see output module.

Comment: As http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/release-notes/?version=3.5.0.GA#modules lays out you should change some settings in the Xcode project, then build the module as normal and finally update the manifest.